# Appending Key/Value Pairs to Python Dictionary in For Loop, Output Ordering

Tags: python, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I am attempting to add the username field to each of the 3 dictionaries within the output list, then I want to add each field to it's respective dictionary as a key/value pair as field#/field value for easily putting the items in a DynamoDB. However, when I output the result of the dictionaries in output list I am receiving out of order fields(keep in mind there are thousands of fields for each object).

```
   #Result stores a list of dicts with username key/value pair and a long list of fields
    result = [{ username: nasa , fields: [Nebula, Moon, Star, ...]},{ username: nationalgeographic, fields: [Grass, Tree, ...] },{ username: kingjames, fields[Basketball, Hardwood, Jersey, ...]}]

    for i in result:
        #For each dict in list
        num = 1
        item = {}
        item['username'] = i['username']
        for tag in i['fields']:
            label_string = 'label' + str(num)
            item[label_string] = tag
            num += 1
        output.append(item.copy())
        #Output should store 3 dicts with username, and labels with tags
    for user in output:
        for key, value in user.items():
            print(key, value)
```

Expected output:

```
username nasa
field1 Nebula
field2 Moon
field3 Star
.
.
.
username nationalgeographic
field1 Grass
field2 Tree
.
.
.
username kingjames
field1 Basketball
field2 Hardwood
field3 Jersey
.
.
.
```

Actual Output

```
username nasa
field333 Black Hole
field282 Asteroid
field122 Mars
.
.
.
username nationalgeographic
field122 Moss
field3323 Bark
field212 Wood
.
.
.
username kingjames
field233 Shoe
field9331 Headband
field211 Mesh
```

Answer (score 0):

Order is not maintained by a `dict` in Python. If you want to keep the keys in the order that they are inserted, you can use an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

```
from collections import OrderedDict
```

Your code would then become

```
#Result stores a list of dicts with username key/value pair and a long list of fields
result = [{ username: nasa , fields: [Nebula, Moon, Star, ...]},{ username: nationalgeographic, fields: [Grass, Tree, ...] },{ username: kingjames, fields[Basketball, Hardwood, Jersey, ...]}]

for i in result:
    #For each dict in list
    num = 1
    item = OrderedDict()
    item['username'] = i['username']
    for tag in i['fields']:
        label_string = 'label' + str(num)
        item[label_string] = tag
        num += 1
    output.append(item.copy())
    #Output should store 3 dicts with username, and labels with tags
for user in output:
    for key, value in user.items():
        print(key, value)
```